# How to declare a number variable where I can save th count of table in my loop

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql

I work wirh oracle Database. I have a plsql code where i run a query in a loop for multiple tables. so, table name is a variable in my code. I would like to have another variable (a single number) that I can call inside the loop and every time it counts the total rows of each table for me

```
declare
  Cursor C_TABLE  is 
    select trim(table_name) as table_name
      from all_tables
     where table_name in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3');

  V_ROWNUM number;

begin
    for m in C_TABLE
      loop 
          for i in ( select column_name 
                      from (
                          select c.column_name
                             from all_tab_columns c
                            where c.table_name = m.table_name 
                              and c.owner = 'owner1' 
                            )  
                    )       
                 loop

                 --I have this:
                  execute immediate ' insert into MY-table value (select ' || i.column_name || ' from ' || m.table_name  || ')';

                 --I want this but it does not work of course: 
                  V_ROWNUM := execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || m.table_name;
                  execute immediate ' insert into MY-table value (select ' || i.column_name || ', ' || V_ROWNUM || ' from ' || m.table_name  || ')';

                    end loop;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

I count not use the "insert into" because I am not selecting from 1 table but the table I want to select from changes every round.

Comment: table MY-table where I am inserting to, just exists in the database and has the required columns

Comment: You're counting rows in each table. The count will be the same regardless of which column you use in the projection. So, do you really want to count the rows for each column in the table? Seems like a waste of cycles.

Comment: yes, I need it for some further Analysis.. that is why I want to count it for each table and then write it into my table infront of all columns

Comment: what APC mean is, in the first Loop you are looping over a table list. for each table you are Looping over all columns in that table. if a table has more than one column, you will get more than one Count of rows for the same table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things wrong with your dynamic SQL.

1. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is not a function: the proper syntax is `execute immediate '<<query>>' into <<variable>>`.
2. An INSERT statement takes a VALUES clause or a SELECT but not both. SELECT would be very wrong in this case. Also note that it's VALUES not VALUE.
3. COLUMN_NAME is a string literal in the dynamic SQL so it needs to be in quotes. But because the SQL statement is itself a string, quotes in dynamic strings need to be escaped so it should be  `'''||column_name||'''.

So the corrected version will look something like this

```
declare
  Cursor C_TABLE  is 
    select trim(table_name) as table_name
      from all_tables
     where table_name in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3');

  V_ROWNUM number;

begin
    for m in C_TABLE
      loop 
          for i in ( select column_name 
                      from (
                          select c.column_name
                             from all_tab_columns c
                            where c.table_name = m.table_name 
                              and c.owner = 'owner1' 
                            )  
                    )       
     loop
         execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || m.table_name into  V_ROWNUM;
         execute immediate 'insert into MY_table values ( ''' || i.column_name || ''', ' || V_ROWNUM || ')';

        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Dynamic SQL is hard because it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. It is good practice to write the statements first as static SQL. Once you have got the basic syntax right you can convert it into dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thank a lot..it works and I appreciate your clear explanation

Answer (score 2):

you can't assign the result of execute immediate  to a variable. it is not a function.

but you can do it by using the `into_clause` e.g.

```
 execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || m.table_name into V_ROWNUM ;
```

Comment: well, this returns error as well. I guess I should have ' ' arount into. right? any how I tried both way and it does not work. here is the error when I do your way:   end;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 66, column 69:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INTO" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum
..

Comment: and if i use single comas around the into i get this error: Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 66
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"